# iMac has blue line on screen at startup

Tags: imac

[image][image]

iMac won't turn on any farther than this.  Blue line down the middle and that's it.  Help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the GPU is hosed to me. Try restarting it while holding down <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> and see if that helps. If not, try holding down <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>power button</kbd> for 10 seconds to reset the SMC. If that also doesn't work, send it to Apple for repair.

Answer (score 0):

Just got mine at assistance, with same problem.

That was the LCD failure. I had to buy a new LCD to replace. No video card or logic board problem.

Hope it can help someone in future.